# nugets and jquery validation compatibility issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, highcharts

I am developing a mvc4 project using Visual Studio 2012, and Oracle 11gr2. 
Recently I added to my project a donet.highcharts.nupkg  and notifications.nupkg. and so far they work pretty well. But I notice that my jquery validations don't work anymore.

I am a little paranoid and every day after finishing my labor I make a backup of the project and when I open a previous project before the installation of the nugget described early the validations work just fine.

Is there any possibility that when these nuggets are installed, it can somehow  mess up my project?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "don't work anymore"? Do you see errors in the JavaScript console, or do some (or all) of the validation rules not get enforced?

Comment: no and that is drive me crazy

Comment: "No" to which? No console errors?

Comment: it is like i never called the validations engine java scripts